# Search/Filter JavaScript Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, search, filter

I am trying to create a search/filter function that allows users to filter an array of JS objects which returns an array populated with data matching the search query.

I wish to be able to search multiple properties in one query so for example; if I search `HKG` it would return all 3 of the objects but if I searched `HKG 12345` it would return the first object in the array.

Another example would be if I were to search `8` it would return the first 2 objects in the array from `sumOfContainers` property matching the query but if I searched `8 SAV` it would return only the first object.

```
results = [];

objects = [
        {laneId:"12345", lane:"HKG-SAV", equipmentType:"20'STD", sumOfContainers: "8", baseline:"$1234", new:"$1234", newSaving:"$1234"},
        {laneId:"12346", lane:"HKG-FRA", equipmentType:"20'STD", sumOfContainers: "8", baseline:"$1234", new:"$1234", newSaving:"$1234"},
        {laneId:"12347", lane:"HKG-LAX", equipmentType:"20'STD", sumOfContainers: "9", baseline:"$1234", new:"$1234", newSaving:"$1234"},     
];

const Search = (toSearch) => {
 for(var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
   for(key in objects[i]) {
     if(objects[i][key].indexOf(toSearch)!=-1) {
       results.push(objects[i]);
     }
   }
  }
}
```

The problem with my attempt is that it will return duplicate data. I have come across a lot of posts online but I am finding difficulty trying to find posts seeking a similar result.

I am trying to achieve this with native JavaScript.

Comment: Just add a `break` right after the `push`. And don't forget to `return results`.

Comment: `Array.from(new Set(results))` would make the results unique. [`objects.filter`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) would probably be helpful, but these conditions (e.g. being able to search “HKG 12345”) are a bit complex.

Comment: @trincot The problem is I still want to filter multiple properties. This doesn't create the exact functionality I am looking for. I also want to break down the query so it can filter by multiple properties.

Comment: @Corona, it does. Just think about it: as soon as you have one key for which there is a match, you don't want to check the other keys for that *same* object. It is only the inner loop that you exit with that break.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yes, I realise making the data not duplicate is quite easy but searching multiple properties in a single query makes things quite difficult. I wonder should I just break the string by spaces and re-run the Search function and then filter out all the duplicates.

Not sure if that if that is the more optimal code to write.

Comment: @trincot The question this points to does not resolve my question. I want to enter a single string as the query to search multiple properties and ensure that the multiple conditions in the query are matched in the data, so yes I do want to check other keys for the same object.

Comment: My first comment answers that. Did you test it? BTW: your question was about a single search string, so if you now speak of multiple conditions, then you need to ask a question about that, providing your attempt. But check for duplicates, as such questions have been asked in several variations a multitude of times already.

Comment: @trincot Yes I did. It does not conclude to the outcome I am seeking. A single search string that can search multiple properties in the table. So you search `8` it will return the first 2 objects, if you search `8 SAV` it will return only the first object. Those are the conditions I set in the question, my attempt also returns duplicates.

Comment: Maybe I could merge the properties into a single string and then break the Search query by spaces and use the broken down query to search for substrings and if any return false, exclude that from my results, would this be my best option or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to split the search string if you consider a space a separator. So you search by "8" and search by "SAV". Obviously searching by "8 SAV" finds no match.

Comment: @trincot I posted an answer to my own question, I saw yours and was wondering would it output similar results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues:

- The duplicates get added because after adding an object, you keep looking for more matches in the *same* object. So if there is any other key that matches, the same object will be added twice
- When the search includes a space, your description says you want to treat that as a separator for multiple search terms, but your code never splits the search argument like that.
- There is no `return` statement in your function
- The key variable is not declared with `var`, `let` or `const`

I would suggest solving this with `filter`: this guarantees that you won't get duplicates. Then require that all search terms have a match: for this you can use `split` and `every`. Then require that there is at least one key that matches a search term: for this you can use `some`:

Don't name your search function with PascalCase, but with camelCase (so `search` instead of `Search`). The common practice is that PascalCase is reserved for constructor/class names.

```
const search = toSearch => {
 let terms = toSearch.split(" ");
 return objects.filter(object =>
   terms.every(term =>
     Object.values(object).some(value =>
       value.includes(term)
     )
   )
  );
}
```

Comment: Simple and clean

Comment: I have to say, I really do respect this answer, simple, clean and elegant and produces the result I intended. I went and read the doc for each of these functions `some`, `every` and `filter`. JavaScript can be beautiful sometimes!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with quite a lousy way of achieving the conditions in the question. If anyone can make this code more optimal that would be terrific.

```
  const search = () => {
      let toSearch = document.getElementById("search").value;
      let lanes = this.objects;
      let result = [];
      const filters = toSearch.split(" ");
      for(let i = 0; i <lanes.length; i++) {
        let search = "";
        let isMatched = true;
        for(let key in lanes[i]) {
            search += lanes[i][key] + " ";
        }
        filters.forEach(filter => {
          if(search.indexOf(filter) == -1) {
            isMatched = false;
            break;
          } 
        });
        if(isMatched) {
          result.push(lanes[i]);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
```

Comment: This function has a different signature than in the question. Why?

Comment: @trincot I rewrote the function to leave out business logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind **lodash**:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const objects = [
        {laneId:"12345", lane:"HKG-SAV", equipmentType:"20'STD", sumOfContainers: "8", baseline:"$1234", new:"$1234", newSaving:"$1234"},
        {laneId:"12346", lane:"HKG-FRA", equipmentType:"20'STD", sumOfContainers: "8", baseline:"$1234", new:"$1234", newSaving:"$1234"},
        {laneId:"12347", lane:"HKG-LAX", equipmentType:"20'STD", sumOfContainers: "9", baseline:"$1234", new:"$1234", newSaving:"$1234"},     
];

const mySearch = (arr, text) => {
  const includesValue = (word, obj) => _.some(obj, (value) => _.includes(value, word));
  const words = _.words(text); 
  return arr
    .filter((obj) => 
      words.every((word) => 
        includesValue(word, obj)
      )
    );
};

console.log(mySearch(objects, 'HKG 12345'));
// [{laneId: '12345', lane: 'HKG-SAV', equipmentType: "20'STD", sumOfContainers: '8', baseline: '$1234', new: '$1234', newSaving: '$1234' }]

console.log(mySearch(objects, '8'));
// [
//   {laneId:"12345", lane:"HKG-SAV", equipmentType:"20'STD", sumOfContainers: "8", baseline:"$1234", new:"$1234", newSaving:"$1234"},
//   {laneId:"12346", lane:"HKG-FRA", equipmentType:"20'STD", sumOfContainers: "8", baseline:"$1234", new:"$1234", newSaving:"$1234"},
// ]

console.log(mySearch(objects, '8 SAV'));
// [{laneId: '12345', lane: 'HKG-SAV', equipmentType: "20'STD", sumOfContainers: '8', baseline: '$1234', new: '$1234', newSaving: '$1234' }]
```